# C# error: not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

I have declared a method in another class and it has an error "not all code paths return a value"

I would like it to return a true or false value to the main program.

But when I declare my method, `public static void`, another error produces, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.

```
public class FileSearch
{
    public static Boolean SearchFiles(string path1, string path2)
    {
        bool isIdentical = false;
        string content1 = null;
        string content2 = null;

        DirectoryInfo d1 = new DirectoryInfo(path1);
        DirectoryInfo d2 = new DirectoryInfo(path2);

        foreach (FileInfo f1 in d1.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            foreach (FileInfo f2 in d2.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                content1 = (File.ReadAllText(f1.DirectoryName + "\\" + f1));
                content2 = (File.ReadAllText(f2.DirectoryName + "\\" + f2));

                isIdentical = content1.Equals(content2, StringComparison.Ordinal);

                if (isIdentical == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want to achieve with this method. As it is now, you return a value after your first comparison. Do you want to get all identical files?

Comment: What is the purpose of your `SearchFiles` method? My gut feeling is that you want to return `false` as soon as you find two different files, and `true` if all files (but shoudn't you compare files with the same name only?) are identical. If so, the `return false` is correctly placed, but the `return true` should be placed after the loops.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# returning error "not all code paths return a value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197410/c-sharp-returning-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your method `SearchFiles` only returns a value if `isIdentical` is `false`. If it's `true`, the method never returns.

To remove this error, write something like this:

```
public static Boolean SearchFiles(string path1, string path2)
{
    // do some work to assign a value to isIdentical
    // note that it would be idiomatic to just write "return isIdentical;" in this case
    // I keep it explicitly here for demonstration purposes 
    if (isIdentical == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

To your second question: If you declare your method as `public static void` you must not `return` any value. `void` means that the method will not give you anything back.

You might want to have a look at this: [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), especially the part about return values.

Edit: Since you have your `if / else` in a `foreach` loop, you need something like this:

```
public static Boolean SearchFiles(string path1, string path2)
{
    foreach(var item in collection)
    {
        // do some work to assign a value to isIdentical
        if (isIdentical == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // in case the collection is empty, you need to return something
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In that case, you're not showing us all your code. The method I wrote will work.

Comment: I have foreach loop, if statement is inside that loop

Comment: If this is in a foreach-loop, you need to return something after the loop in case you loop over an empty collection.

Answer (score 9):

You need to return something if the if condition is not true

you can try this

```
return isIdentical
```

and remove your if statement

so that it looks like this

```
public class FileSearch
{
        public static Boolean SearchFiles(string path1, string path2)
        {
            //Do your other work here
            return isIdentical ;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code....i  think it will help you.

```
public class FileSearch
    {
        public static Boolean SearchFiles(string path1, string path2)
        {
            bool isIdentical = false;
            string content1 = null;
            string content2 = null;
bool result=false;

            DirectoryInfo d1 = new DirectoryInfo(path1);
            DirectoryInfo d2 = new DirectoryInfo(path2);

            foreach (FileInfo f1 in d1.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                foreach (FileInfo f2 in d2.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    content1 = (File.ReadAllText(f1.DirectoryName + "\\" + f1));
                    content2 = (File.ReadAllText(f2.DirectoryName + "\\" + f2));

                    isIdentical = content1.Equals(content2, StringComparison.Ordinal);

                    if (isIdentical == false)
                    {
                       break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result=true;break;

                    }
break;
            }
return result;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Boolean SearchFiles(string path1, string path2)
{
    if (isIdentical == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true or false;
}
```

Comment: you may put else part and return you boolean value from their,,

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Boolean SearchFiles(string path1, string path2)
{

    if(isIdentical == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this at the end of method

return isIdentical;

u are not returning any value.
This may work