# Not all code paths return a value c#

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have declared a method in a class to compare two numbers and I'm having an issue. I'm getting an error saying not all code paths return a value. I want to return an int for every matching number in the char arrays.
[Here is an image of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnu2p.png)

```
public int CompareCodes(string rndselect, string personselect)
{
    char[] rndnumber = rndselect.ToCharArray(); //take the randoms elected one and convert it to a char array
    char[] perNum = personselect.ToCharArray();
    likeness0 = 0;
    likeness1 = 1;

    foreach (char RndNum in rndnumber)
    {
        foreach (char Pnum in perNum)
        {
            if (RndNum == Pnum)
            {
                return likeness1;
            }
            else
            {
                return likeness0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# error: not all code paths return a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903404/c-sharp-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Comment: Hi James. Before you post your question you will be presented some questions that are similar to yours. Simple problems like this usually already have been asked and answered.

Comment: your `int CompareCodes` method must have returned value because  maybe your foreach not run for never!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What should compiler think if your perNum is empty?

Comment: Short, but to the point (+1). Same holds for the other array.

Answer (score 3):

The error says exactly what is wrong with your code. Having a foreach loop doesn't guarantee anything inside the foreach is executed. If `rndnumber` or `perNum` happens to be empty, there is nothing to loop through and your code actually doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

If **rndselect** or **perNum** is empty string. 
So no value is returned.

If you sure these string are always not null. so add

> return 0

at the end of block.