# Why my script show me the crash - not all code path return a value?

Tags: c#

im currently stuck with this crash, I tried to fixed looking for an answer around this comunity but still no working for me. Can somebody please help me?

this is my code

```
public GameObject GetPooledObject()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pooledObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!pooledObjects[i].activeInHierarchy)
            {
                return pooledObjects[i];
            }


        }

        GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject);
        obj.SetActive(false);
        pooledObjects.Add(obj);

    }
```

Comment: You need to add `return obj` at the end.

Comment: What happens if your for loop ends without finding an object?

Comment: Note that "crash" means that the application stops unexpectedly. In its current state, your code won't compile, let alone crash.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you meant to say that you get a compile error. When seeking help with a compile error, it is customary to say what that error is. A crash is when your program has serious problems and stops working when you run it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# error: not all code paths return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903404/c-sharp-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below

```
pooledObjects.Add(obj);
```

add

```
return null;
```

That way the entire method returns no matter what

Comment: Not necessarily return null. It can also return an instance. So “add a return statement” would be more acceptable than “add return null”.

Answer (score 0):

Because as per your method design, you need to return something.